# Como imprimir árvores binárias/genéricas usando C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Estou sofrendo com o seguinte problema: Quero imprimir no terminal o "desenho" de uma árvore.

O algoritmo que estou trabalhando é baseado em uma pilha. Nesta pilha, vou inserindo valores(string ou inteiro) e possuo os seguintes comandos: add, sub, mult e div. Estes comandos pegam os 2 valores que estão no topo da pilha e criam uma árvore com a operação, onde a raiz da árvore é a operação e os filhos são os valores.

Eu consigo imprimir eles em uma linha, seria algo como: ((5 + 2) - (3 * 1)).

Neste exemplo temos como raiz a operação "-", como filhos as operações "+" e "*" e como filhos da adição, 2 e 5, e filhos da multiplicação, 3 e 1.

Mas eu gostaria, também, de imprimir "graficamente". No console sairia algo como:

```
           |-|
            |
    |+|-----------|*|
     |             |
|2|-----|5|   |3|-----|1|
```

A estrutura da minha pilha é a seguinte:

```
struct T;

typedef struct Temp {
    char *data;
    struct Temp *next;
    struct T *firstChild;
} Node;

typedef struct T {
    struct T *next;
    Node *child;
} SonNode;
```

E esta é a minha tentativa de impressão:

```
void treeAux( Node *n, int tam ) {
    if ( n == NULL ) return;
    if ( n == top || n->firstChild == NULL ) addChar(tam, ' ');
    printf("|%s|", n->data);
    if ( n->firstChild == NULL ) return;
    printf("\n");
    addChar( tam+1, ' ');
    printf("|\n");
    SonNode *f = n->firstChild;
    while ( f != NULL ) {
        if ( f != n->firstChild ) addChar(5, '-');
        treeAux( f->child, (int)tam/2 + 6);
        if ( f->next == NULL ) return;
        f = f->next;
    }
}

void tree() {
    treeAux( top, 20 );
}
```

O principal problema que estou tendo é como controlar os espaçamentos.

PS.: Top é uma referência para o topo da pilha. No caso, seria um Node.

PS2.: A principio só são geradas arvores binárias, mas no futuro eu gostaria de adicionar métodos que simplifiquem contas e que tornariam a arvore genérica.

PS3.: O método addChar simplesmente adiciona tam vezes o caractere passado como parâmetro, sem quebrar a linha no final.

Comment: Desafio interessante. Eu nunca me preocupei em desenhar uma árvore, sempre delegava ao graphviz usando a linguagem **dot**.  Essa árvore é cheia ou foi coincidência do exemplo? Posso sugerir tentar não centralizar o nó pai?, deixando-o sempre à esquerda?

Comment: Se por cheia você quer dizer que os filhos sempre serão sub-arvores, não. Ela poderia ser algo como: (3 + (5 * 2)). Assim, um dos filhos da operação "+" seria somente o 3. Acredito que não centralizar a raiz da árvore tiraria o propósito de desenhar ela. Eu tenho uma impressão baseada em HTML, que vai aninhando tags dentro de tags. Mas não estou feliz com ela.

Comment: Talvez essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/801740/1452488) no [so] possa ser útil em algo.

Comment: Tem [essa outra solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13755911/4438007) , que traz uma formatação bem semelhante à sugerido pelo @NickD

Comment: A estratégia que o [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) usa é distinta, mas eu creio que fique elegante, sem falar que aparentemente é fácil de implementar

Answer (score 1):

No livro "Algorithms in C" do Sedgewick tem uma forma bem interessante (e parecidíssima com o que vc quer0 para imprimir árvores (de qualquer tipo, mas particularizada para árvores binárias). Com pequenas alterações você coloca no formato que vc quer.

```
// A função mostraArvore faz um desenho esquerda-direita-raiz
// da árvore x. O desenho terá uma margem esquerda de
// 3b espaços.
void mostraArvore(Arv* a, int b) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        imprimeNo('*', b);
        return;
    }
mostraArvore(a->dir, b+1);
imprimeNo(a->info, b);
mostraArvore(a->esq, b+1);
}

// A função auxiliar imprimeNo imprime o caracter
// c precedido de 3b espaços e seguido de uma mudança
// de linha.
void imprimeNo(char c, int b) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) printf("   ");
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Comment: A impressão que este algoritmo gera seria algo horizontal. Diferente da minha ideia, que seria imprimir ela verticalmente.

Comment: Sim. Você tem razão. Mas, como disse, é uma ideia interessante para tentar a vertical. Eu mesmo estou tentando aqui. Se conseguir, posto.

Answer (score 0):

Achei esse código aqui no StackOverflow. Ainda está vertical, mas já está mais estilizado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define espaco 5


typedef struct no{
   int valor;          // valor of the no
   struct no *esquerda;  // esquerda no
   struct no *direita; // direita no
}no;

//secondary function
void desenha_arvore_horiz(no *arvore, int depth, char *path, int direita)
{
    // stopping condition
    if (arvore== NULL)
        return;

    // increase spacing
    depth++;

    // start with direita no
    desenha_arvore_horiz(arvore->direita, depth, path, 1);

    // set | draw map
    path[depth-2] = 0;

    if(direita)
        path[depth-2] = 1;

    if(arvore->esquerda)
        path[depth-1] = 1;

    // print root after spacing
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<depth-1; i++)
    {
      if(i == depth-2)
          printf("+");
      else if(path[i])
          printf("|");
      else
          printf(" ");

      for(int j=1; j<espaco; j++)
      if(i < depth-2)
          printf(" ");
      else
          printf("-");
    }

    printf("%d\n", arvore->valor);

    // vertical espacors below
    for(int i=0; i<depth; i++)
    {
      if(path[i])
          printf("|");
      else
          printf(" ");

      for(int j=1; j<espaco; j++)
          printf(" ");
    }

    // go to esquerda no
    desenha_arvore_horiz(arvore->esquerda, depth, path, 0);
}

//primary fuction
void draw_arvore_hor(no *arvore)
{
    // should check if we don't exceed this somehow..
    char path[255] = {};

    //initial depth is 0
    desenha_arvore_horiz(arvore, 0, path, 0);
}



no n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;

int main()
{
  n1.valor = 1;
  n2.valor = 2;
  n3.valor = 3;
  n4.valor = 4;
  n5.valor = 5;
  n6.valor = 6;
  n7.valor = 7;

  n1.direita = &n2;
  n1.esquerda = &n3;
  //n2.direita = &n4;
  //n2.esquerda = &n5;
  n3.direita = &n6;
  n3.esquerda = &n7;

  n2.direita = &n3;
  n2.esquerda = &n3;

  draw_arvore_hor(&n1);
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```